# Comparing two comparator objects in Java

Tags: java

If I do the following

```
myObject.myMethod(myClass.getComparator());
```

with

```
public void myMethod(Comparator<? super myOtherObject> comparator) {
if (comparator.equals(myClass.getComparator()) {
 //do sth
}
}
```

and in myClass

```
   static Comparator<ListItem> getComparator() {
        return new Comparator<myOtherObject>() {
            public int compare(myOtherObjectitem1, myOtherObjectitem2) {
                return (Integer.valueOf(myOtherObject.getRating()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(myOtherObject.getRating())));
            }
        };
    }
```

then "//do sth" is not gonna be executed. So the objects I get from getComparator the two times are different. How can that be? Is there a chance to see, which comparator "myMethod" gets?

Comment: unless you implement `equals`, two objects of your class will never be equal.

Comment: Thilo, you mean that in general? How does arraylist.contain then actually work?

Comment: ArrayList.contains (and lots of other things) depend on `equals` being implemented properly. If you don't, then those other tools do, in fact, not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the `equals` method on this line:

```
if (comparator.equals(myClass.getComparator())
```

Since you haven't defined this method explicitly on your Comparator class (which is an anonymous inner class), this defaults to the version inherited from `Object` - which considers two references equal only if they are the exact same object.

And your `getComparator()` method states `return new Comparator() { ... }`, so it's calling the constructor and creating a new object each time it's called.  Thus the result of one call to `getComparator` will be a distinct object, and hence will not be considered equal to, the result of another call.

I can think of two possible ways to change your code so that the equality test returns true:

1. Create the comparator only once, and return this same object from
   `getComparator`.  This would involve a change somewhat like the
   following in `myClass`:

   ```
       private static Comparator<ListItem> cmp = new Comparator<myOtherObject>() {
          public int compare(myOtherObjectitem1, myOtherObjectitem2) {
               return (Integer.valueOf(myOtherObject.getRating()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(myOtherObject.getRating())));
           }
       };

       static Comparator<ListItem> getComparator() {
           return cmp;
       }
   ```
2. Provide an explicit `equals()` implementation (and thus a `hashCode()` one too, ideally).  You can then control exactly which objects are considered equal to one of your comparators.  This might be much easier if you define a concrete class for your comparator rather than it being an anonymous inner class.

---

At the end of the day, though, I fear your approach might not be right.  What does it mean for two comparators to be equal to one another?  I feel this is an ambiguous concept for anything other than data classes, and I would be hesitant to use the `Object.equals` method for this.

(For example, if by equality you mean "they will sort lists in the same order", then I'd add a method to your comparator class called `isEquivalentSortOrder` or something similar.  This way you can specify exactly what you mean without having to rely on the woolly definition of "being the same".)

Comment: thanks heaps :) I get your last point, but for now I went with your first suggestion and it works. So, isequal will only return true for two objects of a class I wrote my own, if they are the EXACT same object, if I dont implement isequal by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create inside `myClass` static variable of `Comparator` like:

```
class myClass{
    public static Comparator<ListItem> = new Comparator<myOtherObject>() {
        public int compare(myOtherObjectitem1, myOtherObjectitem2) {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```